# smooth lines polardiagram - kde / interpolation

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, python-3.6, interpolation, kde-plasma

first attemps have not been successful to smooth/interpolate lines between points.
I tried to implement kdeplot(theta, total) fruitless.

how can i [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd2rQ.jpg)show total=() with a smooth line

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticklabels([])
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticklabels([])
fig.set_axis_bgcolor('#f7fbf5')
ax1.set_ylim(0,3100)
theta=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,len(total))
ax1.plot(theta,total,color='firebrick')      #replaced by ax1.kdeplot(theta,total) w/o success
ax1.grid(False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd2rQ.jpg)

Comment: w/o success, you mean errors? kdeplot is in seaborn API, not matplotlib right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, kde is in the seaborn API.
I paste ax1.sns.kdeplot(theta, total) but the graph did not show a smooth line, it was still cornered (all the points were connected by a straight line)